# How to maintain normalization

Tags: sql-server

I'm Designing a database for a store system. What I have come to design has four tables, Store, Inventory, Product, and Customer. Here's the code I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
    Product_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Description VARCHAR(100),
    Market_price DECIMAL(4,2)
)

CREATE TABLE Inventory(
    Inventory_ID VARCHAR(20),
    Product_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product,
    Quantity int,
    CONSTRAINT Product_Quantity PRIMARY KEY (Inventory_ID,Product_ID)
)

CREATE TABLE Store(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    City VARCHAR(50),
    State VARCHAR(50),
    Inventory_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Inventory,
    Price_mod DECIMAL(4,2)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer(
    Customer_ID VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    City VARCHAR(50),
    State VARCHAR(5),
    Days_loyal int
)
```

Now this won't work because right now Inventory is trying to use a composite primary key, but store doesn't have Product_ID as a column, so Store can't use that as a foreign key. My intended vision for the inventory table would look something like this:

```
inventory_ID        Product_ID      Quantity
123                 5                9
784                 1                5
123                 2                3
784                 2                5
```

From this small example the table would store the Quantity values for a product in a given store. With the way it is setup I would need to have a composite key in order to identify any single row uniquely.
The problem I have is trying to connect the Inventory table to the store table through a foreign key in a way that still satisfies third normal form. Is there a way to do this? Do I need to add another column or would that break normalization?

Comment: Presumably you want to know which store has stock for a product so you need StoreId in the Inventory. Why are some of your ID values defined as varchar? And decimal(4,2) seems a bit limiting, presumably no product can ever be valued at more than 99 whatever?

Comment: No one but you knows what attribute "Inventory_ID" plays in your Inventory table. You will struggle if you personally are unfamiliar with real business process of managing inventory for multiple store locations. If this is a learning exercise, you should start with a system with which you are more familiar. Perhaps you think of inventory as a monolithic entity - but stores contains many products to be sold. The relationship is M-M between them and that is what we often refer to as inventory. Your version does not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the inventory_id form the store table
Add the StoreId to the Inventory table

StoreId, ProductId, Quantity

By querying the inventory table you will know which store it belongs to, what product it is and how many you have in inventory